# How to retrieve parent category when using grouped categories in Highcharts?

Tags: php, highcharts

I am using the grouped categories library here https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories. How would I retrieve a parent category? For example, how would I get/return the category "Fruit" from the graph here: http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/. I have tried this.x which returns both the parent and subcategories of a point. this.category.name would return the subcategory, or "Apple" in the example.

Comment: Could you create jsfiddle example of what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. Talking about tooltip, you can reach parent category name with `this.x.parent.name`. Looks like that you can get any parent level this way;

Try it: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tAq9V/)

Comment: Thanks, this does work for the tooltip, but using this.x.parent.name seems to break the graph functionality. I'm trying to pass in the parent category, which is a date, as a URL parameter to another page using XMLHttpRequest and onreadystatechange. When attempting to use this.x.parent.name to create the URL parameter, no request is made to the other page at all.

Comment: in what callback are you trying to get category name?